# Cartodb: How to make dates appear in Torque time slider

Tags: carto, date, time

I am trying to use my date column as a time-slider in my cartodb map. But it doesn't appear or seem to be an option.

What am I doing wrong?

Here's my map: [Map](https://petulla.cartodb.com/viz/e043322e-f267-11e3-976b-0e230854a1cb/embed_map?title=true&description=true&search=false&shareable=true&cartodb_logo=true&layer_selector=false&legends=false&scrollwheel=true&fullscreen=true&sublayer_options=1&sql=&zoom=3&center_lat=37.19533058280065&center_lon=-90.8349609375)

Here's my data:

[image: Data structure]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to select the column 'funded_at' in the Torque configuration wizard. Right now you are using the column 'cartodb_id'.